# How to add a flash message for new customized action type clone

Tags: sylius, flash-message

By adding a customized action that clones an object, i want to add a flash message after clone is done.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session = new Session();
$session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Message');
```

or

```
public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
}

$this->session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Message');
```